# Why before using code for copy db to document folder Xcode automatically copy db and it is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, fmdb

I used to suing code for copy db from bundle to document folder. But when run Xcode project **before** run my code database has copied to document folder and another problem is: Data base copied is **empty**. And when my code check document folder for exist db result is **YES** therefor not copy complete database to document folder.
I am using Xcode 8.1, iOS8.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you use XCode generated code, and on first call to managedObjectContext database is created. The simplest solution is:

- check if database is empty (amount of records for some entity == 0)
- if yes, copy your file from the bundle to the destination directory.

If your database is used in read-only mode you do not need to copy it into Documents folder at all - you can use it from bundle directory directly.

In this later case you'll need to set up proper key in persistent store options' directory and, copy index files, if you use SQLITE store into bundle as well.